# Images automatically changes after 5 seconds

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to write a code that change images automatically after 5 seconds with cross dissolve or any other animation. Sadly, my code doesn't work. Also I want that images would change all the time.

```
extension UIImageView{
var imageWithFade:UIImage?{
    get{
        return self.image
    }
    set{
        UIView.transition(with: self,
                          duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                            self.image = newValue
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

}

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let firstImage: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "toa-heftiba-461336-unsplash.jpg");
    let secondImage: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "capturing-the-human-heart-475168-unsplash.jpg");

    imgView.imageWithFade = secondImage
}
```

Also, how to make that 3 images would change and not only two of them.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sadly, my code doesn't work

change `duration: 0.5` to `duration: 5`

> Also I want that images would change all the time.
>
> Also, how to make that 3 images would change and not only two of them.
>   Thank you!!

add function

```
 func repeatAnimateImagesChanges(images:NSArray, imageView:UIImageView) {

    if(images.count == 0) {
        return
    }

    var newImage = images.firstObject as! UIImage

    if(imageView.image != nil) {
        for i in 0..<images.count {
            newImage = images.object(at: i) as! UIImage
            if(imageView.image?.isEqual(newImage))! {
                newImage = i == images.count - 1 ? images.firstObject as! UIImage : images.object(at: i + 1) as! UIImage
            }
        }
    }

    imageView.imageWithFade = newImage

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
        self.repeatAnimateImagesChanges(images: images, imageView: imageView)
    }
}
```

pass to it your images and imgView

```
 let img1 = UIImage.init(named: "1")
 let img2 = UIImage.init(named: "2")
 let img3 = UIImage.init(named: "3")

 let array = [img1,img2,img3]

 repeatAnimateImagesChanges(images: array as NSArray, imageView: self.imgView)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you, sir ;)

Answer (score 2):

`UIImage` has a method:

`animatedImage(with images: [UIImage], duration: TimeInterval) -> UIImage?`

You can use this to compose your animated image, and then set it in your image view.

Answer (score 0):

I can maybe simplify the validate answer.

If you have several images and you want change every 5 seconds :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
...
   let imageNames = ["image1", "image2", "image3"]
   var index = 0
   var Timer: Timer!
   @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

   //1.
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image1")
   }

   //2.
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: 
      #selector(self.loop), userInfo: nil, repeats: true) 
   }
   
   //3.
   @objc
   func loop() {
      if index != imageNames.count - 1 {
          index += 1 
          changeImage(index: index)
      }else {
         index = 0
         changeImage(index: index)
      }   
   }

    //4.
    func changeImage(index: Int) {
       UIView.transition(with: self.imageView,
            duration: 2.0, //animation will take 2 seconds
            options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
            animations: {
                self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: 
                self.imageNames[index])
            }, completion: nil)
    }
```

1. Init your imageView with your first image
2. Your timer is ready to call `loop()` every 5 seconds
3. The loop is call. If you have display all images, it will restart at the first image
4. You "notify" to the view `imageView` to begin the transition with next image with a dissolve option. The image is changed thanks to the parameter `animation`

PS: If you want to stop timer i believe you must call `timer.invalidate()`